# can't make orgchart in php

Tags: php, orgchart

I am trying to make orgchart in my code, a have not any idea about this chart. I want to make a a tree like chart, and want data from mysql table. 
Table is : treechart
**id   name    treeid**
1      a       1
2      aa      11
3      aaa     111
4      aaaa    1111
5      ab      12
6      aba     121
7      abb     122
8      ac      13

My code is as below :

```
 <html>
 <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {packages:["orgchart"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
    data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

    // For each orgchart box, provide the name, manager, and tooltip to show.

    <?php 
        include get_template_directory()."/connect/connect.php"; 


        $result = mysql_query("select * from treechart order by id asc");
        $members = array();
        $demo = "[\n";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))   
        {
            $members[$row[2]] = $row[1];
        }
        function search_tree($searchkey)
        {
            return $members[$searchkey];
        }
        foreach($members as $key=>$member)
        {
            if(strlen($key)==1)
            {
                $demo = $demo."['".$member."','','".$member."'],\n";
                $one = $member;
            }
            if(strlen($key)==2)
            {
                $demo = $demo."['".$member."','".$one."',''],\n";
            }
            if(substr($key,0,2)=="11")
            {
                if(strlen($key)==3)
                {
                    $newkey = search_tree("11");
                    echo $newkey."---.";
                }

            }
            $oldkey = strlen($key);
        }
        $demo = substr($demo,0,strlen($demo)-2);
        $demo = $demo."]";
        print_r($newdemo);

    ?>
    data.addRows(<?php echo $demo; ?>);

    // Create the chart.
    var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    // Draw the chart, setting the allowHtml option to true for the tooltips.
    chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true});
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is in $newkey I can't any value, I want the value of 11,12,13 keys value in $newkey. And I have very big amount of data in table, so if anyone have any short coding idea, then help me in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define parent column in your table

id | parrentId | Name

Here is an example

```js
   var orgchart = new getOrgChart(document.getElementById("people"),{
        dataSource: [
         { id: 1, parentId: null, Name: "1"},
         { id: 2, parentId: 1, Name: "2"},
         { id: 3, parentId: 1, Name: "3"}]
    });
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#people {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://www.getorgchart.com/GetOrgChart/getorgchart/getorgchart.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://www.getorgchart.com/GetOrgChart/getorgchart/getorgchart.js"></script>

<div id="people"></div>
```

Comment: I want to remove onwheel zooming effect from this. How can I remove it?

Comment: Set the enableZoom option to false. Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/GetOrgChart/h96yn/

Comment: ok thank you. But my chart is so big. So when I add all nodes it becomes very small and can't read anything. I tried to make zoom false and add horizontal scroll bar to it. But it doesn't work. Have you any idea, how can I do that?

Comment: you can use the scale option with expand/collapse

Comment: yes i try it, but when I set scale, some portion of tree not displayed, so for that I need horizontal scrollbar, but when I set overflow-z it will not display anything.

Comment: you can use the navigation buttons, see the example: http://www.getorgchart.com/GetOrgChart/getorgchart-demos/first-look.html